# stateless framework and stateful framework

Tags: java, frameworks

What is a stateful and stateless framework in java? I read play framework FAQ's and they are  mentioned as a stateless framework and seam, wicket, etc are stateful.So what is exactly difference on this. Can I say JSF is a stateful framework?

Comment: http://www.slideshare.net/programr/terracotta-stateless-versus-stateful-apps-presentation

Comment: Component based frameworks are stateful for example JSF.its not depends on http request and response of object.coming to Struts is depends on http reqeust and response.http is stateless proctocol.Is it correct?.any thing wrong on this Please correct to me